# display dns cache in windows

Tags: python, caching, dns

I'm trying to display windows cache and the only way I found is using subprocess through command line to display the cache. Is there any library that helps collect such data from windows rather than using cmd.exe or Should just I stick with the command line.

```
import subprocess
import os

def _list_dns_cache():
    values = {}
    # values['HostNames']=[]
    values['hostvalues']=[]
    cache   = os.popen2("ipconfig /displaydns")
    source  = cache[1].read()
    for row in source.split('\n'):
        if ': ' in row:
            key, value = row.split(': ')
            key1 = row.split('..')[0]
            values['hostvalues'].append({'key':key1 ,'value':value})

    return values
```

Comment: This is a windows job, so you need to use the cmd.

Comment: :/. I will try to work something out rather than using the cmd.

Comment: Can you give your full code?

Comment: I'm still using the subprocess and it is the one on the main thread.